# How to fetch values based on date range in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have 2 dfs df1 and df2.
df1 have 2 record dates (Base date and followup date),
(Scenario 1) At first I need to match the exact Record_date1 to Drug_Date if it is matched drug name should be update to the corresponding date (i.e PID = 345).
(Scenario 2) If the date is not matched I have to fetch the minimum drug_date of the PID based on daterange like (**where min(drug_Date) between Record_date_1(-7 days) and Record_date_1(+45 days)**)

Here I given the sample set and expected output below.

```
PID Record_Date_1   D1  Record_Date_2   D2
123 22-04-1996     5.3    30-10-1996    5.4
234 16-06-1994     6.8    13-12-1994    7.2
345 18-09-2000     7.5    24-02-2001    8.9
456 20-02-2001     8.5    20-08-2001    9.4


PID Drug_Date   Drugs
123 23-04-1996  Biguanides
123 28-04-1996  Sulphynureas
123 31-10-1996  SGLT2
234 15-06-1994  Insulin
234 14-12-1994  Biguanides
345 18-09-2000  DPP4-inhibitor
345 24-02-2001  Incretin
456 21-02-2001  Biguanides
456 26-08-2001  Sulphynureas
```

Expected output :

```
PID Record Date D1  Record Date_2   D2  Drug_ Date1 D1_Drugs       Drug_ Date2  D2_Drugs
123 22-04-1996  5.3 30-10-1996     5.4  23-04-1996  Biguanides      31-10-1996  sulphynureas
234 16-06-1994  6.8 13-12-1994     7.2  15-06-1994  Insulin         14-12-1994  Biguanides
345 18-09-2000  7.5 24-02-2001     8.9  18-09-2000  DPP4-inhibitor  24-02-2001  Incretin
456 20-02-2001  8.5 20-08-2001     9.4  21-02-2001  Biguanides      26-08-2001  sulphynureas
```

If you need any clarification please let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function like this

```
my_match <- function(x, y) {
  f <- function(i, j) {
    pos <- which(j >= i - 7L & j <= i + 45L)
    pos[[which.min(j[pos])]]
  }
  x <- as.Date(x, "%d-%m-%Y")
  y <- as.Date(y, "%d-%m-%Y")
  out <- match(x, y)
  ifelse(is.na(out), vapply(x, f, integer(1L), y), out)
}
```

Then, you can just

```
df1$Drug_Date1 <- df2$Drug_Date[my_match(df1$Record_Date_1, df2$Drug_Date)]
df1$D1_Drug <- df2$Drugs[my_match(df1$Record_Date_1, df2$Drug_Date)]
df1$Drug_Date2 <- df2$Drug_Date[my_match(df1$Record_Date_2, df2$Drug_Date)]
df1$D2_Drug <- df2$Drugs[my_match(df1$Record_Date_2, df2$Drug_Date)]
```

Output

```
> as.data.frame(df1)
  PID Record_Date_1  D1 Record_Date_2  D2 Drug_Date1        D1_Drug Drug_Date2      D2_Drug
1 123    22-04-1996 5.3    30-10-1996 5.4 23-04-1996     Biguanides 31-10-1996        SGLT2
2 234    16-06-1994 6.8    13-12-1994 7.2 15-06-1994        Insulin 14-12-1994   Biguanides
3 345    18-09-2000 7.5    24-02-2001 8.9 18-09-2000 DPP4-inhibitor 24-02-2001     Incretin
4 456    20-02-2001 8.5    20-08-2001 9.4 21-02-2001     Biguanides 26-08-2001 Sulphynureas
```

Data (`df1`)

```
structure(list(PID = c(123, 234, 345, 456), Record_Date_1 = c("22-04-1996", 
"16-06-1994", "18-09-2000", "20-02-2001"), D1 = c(5.3, 6.8, 7.5, 
8.5), Record_Date_2 = c("30-10-1996", "13-12-1994", "24-02-2001", 
"20-08-2001"), D2 = c(5.4, 7.2, 8.9, 9.4), Drug_Date1 = c("23-04-1996", 
"15-06-1994", "18-09-2000", "21-02-2001"), D1_Drug = c("Biguanides", 
"Insulin", "DPP4-inhibitor", "Biguanides"), Drug_Date2 = c("31-10-1996", 
"14-12-1994", "24-02-2001", "26-08-2001"), D2_Drug = c("SGLT2", 
"Biguanides", "Incretin", "Sulphynureas")), row.names = c(NA, 
-4L), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(PID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Record_Date_1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), D1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), Record_Date_2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), D2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 2), class = "col_spec"))
```

Data (`df2`)

```
structure(list(PID = c(123, 123, 123, 234, 234, 345, 345, 456, 
456), Drug_Date = c("23-04-1996", "28-04-1996", "31-10-1996", 
"15-06-1994", "14-12-1994", "18-09-2000", "24-02-2001", "21-02-2001", 
"26-08-2001"), Drugs = c("Biguanides", "Sulphynureas", "SGLT2", 
"Insulin", "Biguanides", "DPP4-inhibitor", "Incretin", "Biguanides", 
"Sulphynureas")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -9L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    PID = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), Drug_Date = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector")), Drugs = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 2), class = "col_spec"))
```